# Why does Finasteride effeminize men despite it increasing serum testosterone and inhibiting estrogen production?

Tags: testosterone, estrogen

[Effects](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/finasteride-oral-route/description/drg-20063819#:%7E:text=Finasteride%20blocks%20the%20action%20of,hair%20growth%20on%20the%20scalp.) of Finasteride

> Finasteride blocks the action of an enzyme called 5-alpha-reductase.
> This enzyme changes testosterone to another hormone that causes the
> prostate to grow or hair loss in males. It will increase testosterone
> levels in the body, which decreases prostate size and increases hair
> growth on the scalp.

It also inhibits [aromatase-independent testosterone conversion into estrogenic steroids](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16386416/#:%7E:text=Estrogens%20are%20generated%20mainly%20by,can%20stimulate%20the%20estrogen%20receptor.)

> the synthesis of estrogenic steroids was blocked by inhibition of
> testosterone conversion into dihydrotestosterone using a 5
> alpha-reductase inhibitor finasteride, suggesting that they are
> generated downstream of dihydrotestosterone

This in thoery must masculinize people who take it, **but** it instead femnizes them. [Source](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11930-020-00276-2#:%7E:text=Finasteride%20causes%20certain%20male%20individuals,via%205%C9%91%2DR%20with%20finasteride.).

> Finasteride causes certain male individuals to show symptoms of
> demasculinization and feminization after exposure

---

### Why? What's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finasteride inhibits conversion of testosterone to dihydrotestosterone (DHT). This is also why it is used to prevent androgenic alopecia.

DHT is [considerably more potent](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC507713/) than testosterone in the prostate and at the androgen receptor in general. In fact [DHT is the most potent endogenous androgen and also cannot be converted to oestrogen.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK557634/)

This makes sense, if you do not convert testosterone to a more potent form then the overall effect on the androgen receptor is reduced, despite total serum testosterone increasing.

Comment: Interestingly, the last linked paper mentions that Finasteride treats and decreases the risk of prostate cancer, but patients undergoing these therapies have increased rates of higher-grade cancers.